# XML preview using XSLT in SharePoint Online & Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, power-automate

I am exploring SharePoint Online platform. There is a requirement to preview XML using XSLT.

1. Could you please suggest any existing feature of SharePoint Online or any customization possible to display XML data as HTML?
2. Is there any workflow task/feature in Power Automate workflow where attached XML file in workflow can have a HTML preview capability using the XSLT.

I really appreciate any pointers or suggestions.

Thank you very much for your support and time.

Please note: I am a beginner to the SharePoint Online, Power Automate and dot net framework.

Regards,
AK

Comment: Any help or pointers is appreciated.